# How do Binance API calculate priceChangePercent in 24h to other time frame?

Tags: binance

I understand that there is a 24 hour price change statistics and i am trying to develop my app to 4 hour instead. I have read the docs provided by Binance at https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md and stackoverflow at [How do Binance API calculate priceChangePercent in 24h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321891/how-do-binance-api-calculate-pricechangepercent-in-24h) but i couldn't get any clue. I have tried using client.get_historical_klines or client.get_klines but couldn't retrieve the result i want. I am lost here please if anybody can help would be much appreciated. Thanks !

```
def test1():
    print(time.ctime())
    try:
        candles = client.get_historical_klines('BTCUSDT', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_4HOUR, "19 Dec, 2019", "19 Dec, 2019" )
    except BinanceAPIException as e:
        print(e.status_code)
        print(e.message)
    return candles[0]

print(test1())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show any script.

Comment: hi thanks for the response. i have added the script above.